# Rotation metadata not changing when encoding with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, metadata

[**UPD:** Checking metadata with `exiftool -rotation`]

Been struggling for a few days, here is the setup:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate="-90" output.mp4
```

changes the output.mp4 rotation metadata. At the same time:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -metadata:s:v:0  rotate="-90" output.mp4
```

does not.Why can't I encode and change rotation field at the same time? Tried with different codecs and rotation angles. Other metadata fields are changing just fine. Using:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c libx264 intermediate.mp4
ffmpeg -i intemediate.mp4 -metadata:s:v:0 rotate="-90" output.mp4
```

is always an option, but seems wasteful.

Comment: Which ffmpeg version?

Comment: Got the same result on local machine with ffmpeg 4.2.3 and  in google colab with ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1

Comment: try to add `-noautorotate` before input

Comment: Nope, ffmpeg -noautorotate -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -metadata:s:v:0  rotate="-90" output.mp4  still doesn't change video orientation